# How can i take a photo of a moving object with the object in focus and the background having motion blur?

Tags: motion-blur, panning

I have seen pictures that must of been taken with a slow shutter speed, the car was in focus but the background had motion blur, how can this happen?

Comment: Also related: [How does one photograph a car race?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12839/11924)

Comment: Also related: [What equipment and settings do I use for panning shots of moving objects?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8795/11924)

Comment: Don't you love it when the the question is closed with a dupe that isn't really much of a match before the other question that is a *really good match* can be added by another member?

Comment: @MichaelClark the dup selection is fine this time, isn't it?

Comment: @EuriPinhollow Not really, because the examples in the OP and the answers to that question are mostly about other things. The one listed in the comments is a MUCH BETTER match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow down the shutter and track the car.  It takes some practice but it's pretty easy.

I have some examples of some results on my [flickr page](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mwwhited/8431745970/in/album-72157632654868586/), [More](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mwwhited/albums/72157632654751134).